# For practical purposes does this malloc() code initialize a variable size array?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

So if I have some data type called type, does the following code pretty much initialize a variable size array in C?

```
type InitValue; //initial value I want every array element to have. For my purposes it is a struct I defined.
int VarSize=5; //variable integer size, set to 5 here arbitrarily 

type *VarArr=(type*)malloc(VarSize*sizeof(type)); //My variable length "array"

for (int k=0; k<VarSize; k++){
VarArr[k]=InitValue; //initializing values in "array"
}
```

Then, for all intents and purposes can I just treat VarArr to be an array of "type" data of length "n"? It seems like it but I heard it technically is something else apparently, and I am definitely not a programmer so I was wondering if the above is bad practice for some computer science reason. Just for more info, I'm doing a very simple "just run this function" program.

Also, are there any IDEs that support C99? I've been using OnlineGDB but it starts throwing weird errors when my VLAs become large and comparing it to Programiz it seems to be a compiler specific error.

I've tried making Visual Studio use C99 for like a half hour before I learned it doesn't support it (despite some yahoo from a university claiming it can be done in the first Google search result I found).

Comment: No 'bad practice' about it, this is done all the time. Wherever you heard or read that, treat that source accordingly in future. Your question about IDEs is off topic.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Sorry Barmar, is that a post showing its "bad practice" sometimes?

Comment: Only the `(type*)` part. Just write `type *VarArr = malloc(...);`

Comment: *Can I just treat VarArr to be an array of "type" data of length "n"?* Only if `n == VarSize`.

Comment: Ok, thank you Barmar! Also, thank you user207421, Weather Vane as well.

Comment: What you probably heard is that arrays and pointers are not equivalent as types.. But for what you're doing, they're equivalent.

Comment: For example, `int foo[10][20]` and `int *foo[10]` are not equivalent. The first is a 2-dimensional array, the second is a 1-dimensional array of pointers.

Comment: The memory allocation isn't an array. It only behaves like an array that has been passed to a function, which decays to a pointer.

Comment: So is `n` equal to `VarSize`? Did you mean to just use `VarSize` instead of `n`? It kind of significantly changes the question.

Comment: Oops forgot to fix that KamilCuk. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. It's a pointer, not an array. `sizeof(VarArr)` will return the size of the pointer. `&VarArr` will return the address of the pointer. etc.

You could consider it to be a pointer to the first element of an array.

```c
int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n );
```

is similar to

```c
int a[ n ];
int *p = a;   // int *p = &( a[0] );
```

Still, there are differences. The memory allocated with `malloc` must be manually freed, but that also means it can outlast the scope in which the allocation occurred.

```c
int *f( size_t n ) {
   int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n );
   return p;  // ok, but don't forget to free the memory later.
}
```

```c
int *f( size_t n ) {
   int a[ n ];
   int *p = a;   // int *p = &( a[0] );
   return p;     // Not ok. (See footnote 1.)
}
```

---

1. Technically, returning a pointer to an automatic variable is valid, but dereferencing the returned pointer isn't.

Comment: Re “Technically, returning a pointer to an automatic variable is valid, but dereferencing the returned pointer isn't.”: It is not clear what you mean by “valid,” because that term is not defined in the C standard, but the value of a pointer become indeterminate when the lifetime of the object it points to ends (C 2018 6.2.4 2). So using the returned pointer for any purpose, e.g., arithmetic, comparison, or printing, will not have any determined value.

Comment: Right, and it's perfectly fine to have a variable with an indeterminate value. It's using it that's not. (Ok, I was a overly specific when I said dereferencing.)